# CloudDeploy function returning error

Tags: cloud-deploy

I've created a very simple API that imports the "Plaintext" of a URL or a PDF. Here is my code:

```
urlScraperTest = APIFunction[
   {"url" -> "String"},
   Import[#url, "Plaintext"] &];
```

and deployed it to the Wolfram Cloud:

```
CloudDeploy[urlScraperTest, "urlScraper", Permissions -> "Public", CloudObjectNameFormat -> "CloudUserUUID"]
```

CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/user-7d8eeec4-69a3-4149-bc75-10de306a3cbd/urlScraper"]

This code works fine if I pass it some URLs, e.g. here is a recipe that I am able to scrape from my browser:

```
https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/user-7d8eeec4-69a3-4149-bc75-10de306a3cbd/urlScraper?url=https://www.foodandwine.com/recipes/beef-wellington
```

But when I try to pass the code a PDF file name, it produces an (unhelpful) "$Failed" error. For instance, here is a simple pdf stored in a cloud location:

```
https://bbf184a8c110ea5f6bb4192bc1d23ad5.cdn.bubble.io/f1703793538605x556426251682794500/Perfect%20Chocolate%20Chip%20Cookies%20Recipe%20-%20NYT%20Cooking.pdf
```

If I enter this location in my browser search bar directly, the PDF renders correctly. But if I try to pass this URL to my function

```
https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/user-7d8eeec4-69a3-4149-bc75-10de306a3cbd/urlScraper?url=https://bbf184a8c110ea5f6bb4192bc1d23ad5.cdn.bubble.io/f1703793538605x556426251682794500/Perfect%20Chocolate%20Chip%20Cookies%20Recipe%20-%20NYT%20Cooking.pdf
```

It produces a "$Failed" message. Note: If I call the URLScraperTest[] function directly from a local MMA notebook using the above URL, it *does* return the results I expect with no error.

Can someone help shed some light on this behavior and suggest a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I should have mentioned that I need to call with Wolfram Cloud function from another system, not from Mathematica. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your url will be url-decoded but you want to keep %20s for `Import` so you need to encode it in your request. At least I am assuming this is the problem.

```
url = "https://bbf184a8c110ea5f6bb4192bc1d23ad5.cdn.bubble.io/\
f1703793538605x556426251682794500/Perfect%20Chocolate%20Chip%\
20Cookies%20Recipe%20-%20NYT%20Cooking.pdf"

Import[URLDecode@url, "Plaintext"] (* $Failed *)
```

So your final request needs to look like this, does it?

```
URLBuild[apiURL, {"url" -> url}]
```

> "...?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbbf184a8c110ea5f6bb4192bc1d23ad5.cdn.bubble.io%
> 2Ff1703793538605x556426251682794500%2FPerfect%2520Chocolate%2520Chip%
> 2520Cookies%2520Recipe%2520-%2520NYT%2520Cooking.pdf"

Comment: Thanks @kuba. I'm not quite sure I follow your solution. I can get this work from a Mathematica notebook, but not from calling the API from outside of Mathematica (I'd would like to use this function as part of a non-MMA web app I am building. Thank you.

Comment: @MSC02476 my point was that since the input is url-decoded before Import is used then you need to have a valid encoded url encoded another time to account for that.